# Tiempo de respuesta al consumir API IONIC 4

Tags: angular, api, ionic

Estoy consumiendo un servicio y tengo el siguiente  problema es que a la primera vez que ingreso a la view no carga la información, al ingresar la segunda vez si me carga todo... supongo que es por el tiempo de respuesta de la petición, ya lo intente haciendo con una promesa pero tampoco funciona... Como puedo controlar esto para que la información me cargue a la primera vez que ingreso a la pagina

también intenten llamando la función  en los métodos `ngOnInit`, i`onViewDidLoad`, `ionViewDidEnte` y sin ningún resultado exitoso...

service.ts

```
cargarCampos(id) {
    let resp = this.http.get(this.url2)

    resp.map(resp => resp)
      .subscribe((rp: any) => {

        if (rp.respuesta) {
          this.CamposName.push(...rp.datos);
        } else {
          this.CamposName = [];
        }

      }, err => {

        if (err.status == 0) {
        }
      });

    return this.CamposName;
  }
```

page.ts

```
   ConsultarNamesCampos() {

    this.CamposName = this.formulario.cargarCampos(this.id_formulario);

   }
```

version CLI 4.10.3

Answer (score 0):

importa esta libreria

```
import ‘rxjs/add/operator/timeout’;
```

te dejo un ejemplo

```
 return Observable.from(
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content - Type", "application / json");
    this.http
      .post(this.url + " / api/", JSON.stringify(credentials), {
        headers: headers
      })
      .timeout(15000)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          let data = res.json();
          resolve(data);
        },
        err => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
  })
);
```